# Making an algorithm that assigns units of electricity to days of the week and figures out which is the least

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

They will receive free electric one day a week. They will not pay for the day that they use the least amount of electric

Write an algorithm that will:

· Allow the user to input the day of the week and then unit of units of electric used.

· Compare them until all comparisons are completed.

Output the day that will be free of charge.

I've tried using a list on a variable that assigns the units of electricity to a slot. That means I can pull that data later on so I can compare the different slots.

```
def ElectricSupplier():
  # The slot system I was talking about \/
  electric = ["","","","","","",""]
  day = 0
  # Repeating the input function so that they can input 7 different units into 
  # a different slot (not sure if this is the right way of going about it)
  for i in range(7):
    day = day + 1
    electric[electric + 1] = int(input("Enter Units Of Electricity Used - "))
```

It is meant to output "Xday is the day that you will get free electricity"
Instead at the moment I just get "can only concatenate list (not "int") to list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
electric[electric + 1] = int(input("Enter Units Of Electricity Used - "))
```

This should be changed to

```
electric[i] = int(input("Enter Units Of Electricity Used - "))
```

`electric` is an array so you cant use it as an index.

Edit:

```
def ElectricSupplier():
  # The slot system I was talking about \/
  # Repeating the input function so that they can input 7 different units into 
  # a different slot (not sure if this is the right way of going about it)
    minValue = 1000000
    minDay = 0
    weekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    for i in range(7):
        value = int(input("Enter Units Of Electricity Used - "))
        if minValue>value:
           minValue=value
           minday=i
    print("lowest usage: %d in %s   " % (minValue, weekDays[minDay]))
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure how to print the lowest value in a day

Comment: The algorithm will keep track of the minimum value and the day, If we got a value lower than the minValue then we will assign that value to minValue and change the `minDay` to i. Finally, we can get the weekday by using the `minDay` as an index.